# How to get path of nodejs executable on runtime

Tags: node.js

I have to execute a node command within another node process as shown below:

```
require('child_process').exec (`${<path of current node executable>} someModule`);
```

How can i retrieve the node executable path on runtime to execute this command.

Comment: `process.execPath` or possibly even `process.argv0` depending on what you actually want. Surely this has been asked here before.

Comment: Perhaps you should just use [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) where it will just run a new instance of nodejs for you to run the specified script file without you having to specify the path to node.exe at all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`process.execPath` should be what you require.

`process.argv0` is not alway pointed to `node` binary.

As the in the [official Node document](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv0).

> The process.argv0 property stores a read-only copy of **the original value of argv[0]** passed when Node.js starts.

In the example of the official document, it demo the case that `process.argv0` is not the node binary. `customArgv0` is for `exec`'s `-a` flag.

```
$ bash -c 'exec -a customArgv0 ./node'
> process.argv[0]
'/Volumes/code/external/node/out/Release/node'
> process.argv0
'customArgv0'
```

If you are trying to execute another node app, how about taking a look at [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)?

You code then should be as follows.

```
// fork()'s first argument should be the same as require();
// except that fork() executes the module in a child process
require('child_process').fork(`someModule`);
```

As stated in document, `fork()` use the same node binary as `process.execPath`, or you can specify other node binary to execute the module.

> By default, child_process.fork() will spawn new Node.js instances
>   using the process.execPath of the parent process. The execPath
>   property in the options object allows for an alternative execution
>   path to be used.

Comment: the issue with fork is on windows it can create a node.exe window that pops up

Comment: For people coming to this thread later, they can have a try on `fork()` with `windowsHide` option set to `true`. As the official document reads that `fork()` is a special case of `spawn()` and from the source code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c1b2f6afbe03841a6f0ca5fa363ceb5bcdcfe638/lib/child_process.js#L116) we can know that the options of `fork()` is actually passed to `spawn()` after some default options made.